Largest Local Values in a Matrix (Deep Copy)
I have been stuck trying to debug the solution for this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-local-values-in-a-matrix/description/
The objective is to return the max value from every 3x3 sub-matrix in a given matrix.
I create an initial matrix (res) of size (n-2) x (n-2) filled with 0's.
For every index in res, I visit the given original matrix grid and iterate from i to i+2 through the rows and columns and update the max.
After doing the above process (finding max in a 3x3 matrix), I return the max value (maxVal).
Problem:

It accesses all the elements and indices properly, I have tried incrementing and decrementing all the indices used in the code.

I still can't cant seem to understand why the correct max values are not being assigned to the res matrix


Here's the Python code:
def largestLocal(grid: list[list[int]]) -> list[list[int]]:
        n = len(grid[0])
        res = [[0] * (n-2)] * (n-2)
        
        def findMax(i:int, j:int,  mat: list[list[int]]) -> int:
            maxVal = 0
            for r in range(i, i+3):
                # print("Row:", r)
                for c in range(j, j+3):
                    # print("Column: {}, Element: {}, Max: {}".format( c, grid[r][c], maxVal))
                    maxVal = max(maxVal, grid[r][c])
            return maxVal
        
        for i in range(0, n-2):
            for j in range(0, n-2): 
                res[i][j] = findMax(i, j, grid)

        return res


Test case: [[9,9,8,1],[5,6,2,6],[8,2,6,4],[6,2,2,2]]
Expected output: [[9,9],[8,6]]
Output obtained: [[8,6],[8,6]]

I did find a better way from my friend; appending all the values of the 3x3 matrix to a list and returning the max value of it.

You need to use:
res = [[0] * (n - 2) for _ in range(n - 2)]

instead of
res = [[0] * (n-2)] * (n-2)

In the latter version, you're technically using the same first list, (n - 2) times, instead of creating a list of list. Any change you make in any list, will be reflected to other (n - 3) lists.
This is a common mistake. [[0] * (n-2)] * (n-2) creates a list containing (n - 2) "references" to the same inner list [0] * (n - 2). Modifying any inner list will affect all the others, because they all "point to" the same object in the allocated memory.

Code:
def largestLocal(grid: list[list[int]]) -> list[list[int]]:
    n = len(grid)
    res = [[0] * (n - 2) for _ in range(n - 2)]

    def findMax(i: int, j: int) -> int:
        maxVal = 0
        for r in range(i, i + 3):
            for c in range(j, j + 3):
                maxVal = max(maxVal, grid[r][c])
        return maxVal

    for i in range(0, n - 2):
        for j in range(0, n - 2):
            res[i][j] = findMax(i, j)

    return res


print(largestLocal([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]))


Prints
[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]


You can simplify it to:
def largestLocal(grid: list[list[int]]) -> list[list[int]]:
    m, n = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    res = [[0] * (n - 2) for _ in range(m - 2)]
    for i in range(m - 2):
        for j in range(n - 2):
            res[i][j] = max(grid[ii][jj] for ii in range(i, i + 3) for jj in range(j, j + 3))
    return res

print(largestLocal([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]))


Prints
[[2], [2], [2]]


That has worked the magic, appreciate it!
